# getdate() is not finding all records

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I am trying to get all records from a data extension with a date that is within the last 7 days.

The data in the date field (INIT_SUB_TMSTMP) looks like this:

```
"2017-10-06-13.03.33.483000"
```

My current WHERE clause:

```
WHERE datediff( dd, CAST(LEFT(INIT_SUB_TMSTMP,10) as datetime), getDate() )
< 7
```

The records in the data extension have increased by 12,362 compared to last week but when I run this query to get only those 12k records, it returns only 7500 so there has got to be something wrong with how I"m pulling the date?  Any ideas?

Thank in Advance

Comment: You are using data time, hence it is looking at a precise match, try casting it as a date (relaxing the time constraint)

Comment: can you also post your entire query?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest handling the time portion of your date differently.  The `convert()` to `date` will strip the time from the `getDate()` -- making it midnight (`00:00`).

This will select rows where `init_sub_tmstmp` is within the 7 days:

```
select
field1
, field2
from DataExtension
where init_sub_tmstmp >= convert(date, getdate()-7)
```

If you need to select rows that are exactly 7 days ago, you can use something like this:

```
select
field1
, field2
from DataExtension
where init_sub_tmstmp >= convert(date, getdate()-7)
and init_sub_tmstmp < convert(date, getdate()-6)
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment:

```
select 
  PREFIX
, FIRST_NAME
, MIDDLE_NAME
, LAST_NAME
, SUFFIX
, [Email Address]
, SOURCE_COUNTRY_ISO
, LANGUAGE_CODE
, convert(date, left(INIT_SUB_TMSTMP,10)) AS INIT_SUB_TMSTMP 
from DATA_EXTENTION 
where convert(date, left(INIT_SUB_TMSTMP,10)) >= convert(date, getdate()-7)
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback everyone.   Using the advise of Data_Kid, I used a substring to drop the time stamp (I noticed the filed was a string and not a date data type after I posted this question).  Then using the advise from Adam Springs, I used the convert function.

I am getting an error when running the query now though:

Comment: I hit enter too fast:
I am getting an error when running the query now though:

select
PREFIX,
FIRST_NAME,
MIDDLE_NAME,
LAST_NAME,
SUFFIX,
[Email Address],
SOURCE_COUNTRY_ISO,
LANGUAGE_CODE,
SUBSTRING(INIT_SUB_TMSTMP,1,CHARINDEX('.',INIT_SUB_TMSTMP)-4) AS INIT_SUB_TMSTMP
from DATA_EXTENTION
where INIT_SUB_TMSTMP >= convert(date, getdate()-7)

Comment: I updated my answer with an additional example.